# Ubuntu 20.04: Youtube playback not working

Tags: video, youtube

I'm facing this weird issue where youtube stops working after a while. It loads, but the video itself does not play. It waits for a while and then it says if video doesn't start playing, restart your device. I tried a restart and it works fine. Few minutes later, i'm facing the same problem again.

I've tried installing the various codec solutions that others have suggested as answers to similar questions, I've installed ffmpeg, ubuntu-restricted-extras, and a few others I don't remember from way back on a fresh install of ubuntu when i first installed it.

Comment: If you can not remember what you did I suggest a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have also open Citrix Workspace app. 20.3. If I close Citrix, local videos are playing again. I reverted from Citrix Workspace 20.03 to 20.01. After reboot, I opended Citrix Workspase and I connected bact to remote, local video is playing again as it should. Let's see, how long it stays good..

Comment: wow, I'm using citrix as well. This might just be the culprit. I'm not facing any issues when citrix workspace is not open.